# cliffDelta error: All values of t are equal to 1 \n Cannot calculate confidence intervals

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to calculate the confidence interval of the cliff's delta, but I am getting an error I am not sure how to resolve. Error:

```
[1] "All values of t are equal to  1 \n Cannot calculate confidence intervals"
Error in signif(CI1, digits = digits) :
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Here is a reproducible example that throws this error. Any help is appreciated!

```
df <- data.frame(
value =  c(9.943347e-03, 9.547829e-04, 3.965193e-03, 2.401066e-03, 1.561308e-03, 1.471534e-03, 2.486966e-04, 6.854217e-04, 1.671067e-04, 9.023359e-04, 8.577253e-05, 3.697852e-04),
group = c(rep("ctrl",6), rep("exp",6)))

cliffDelta(value ~ group,df, ci =T, conf = 0.95)
```

Cheers

Comment: looks like your values are not different enough.  try `value = rnorm(12)`, you'll see the function runs without error.

Comment: @andrew_reece what you're saying is that cliffDelta() doesn't handle data that is perfectly split between the two groups?